# Sort order discrepancy in javascript key value objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set up a jsFiddle example of my problem: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3s6Qf/1/)

Given this html:

```
<select id="drop1" data-jsdrop-data="countries"></select>
<select id="drop2" data-jsdrop-data="countries2"></select>​
```

And the following javascript:

```
var countries = {"1" : "Albania", "5" : "Australia","2": "United Arab Emerates"};
var countries2 = {"AL" : "Albania", "AU" : "Australia", "AE" : "United Arab Emerates"};


function loadJSOptions(selector, list) {
    $.each(list, function (key, value) {
        $(selector).append($("<option></option>").val(key).html(value));
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('select[data-jsdrop-data]').each(function() {
       var selector = $(this);
       var listname = selector.attr("data-jsdrop-data");
       var listvalue = null;
       eval("listvalue = " + listname + ";");
       loadJSOptions(selector, listvalue);
    });
});
```

​
Can anyone explain to me why the list with the Alpha key gets listed based on the order entered while the list with the numeric key gets sorted based on the key?  If you look at the jsFiddle results, you'll see that drop1 shows Albania, United Arab Emerates, Australia while drop2 shows Albania, Australia, United Arab Emerates.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Object keys have no order, they just are.

Comment: You cant rely on object keys to be in any particular order. If order is important, use an array.

Comment: Please, don't use `eval` but an array or something for your country-objects

Comment: They appear the same to me in Firefox, but as @Bergi said, there is no guarantee of order in the spec.

Comment: I guess I would've expected to get both the lists in the order in which they were entered.  IOW, key and value should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object properties are not ordered, if you enumerate them the order is implementation-defined. They often are stored in the order the object literals were parsed, but you can't rely on that. For example, numeric keys (as in `countries1`) seem to be sorted in your browser.

If you want a definite order, use an array (an object with numeric keys) and iterate them:

```
var lists = {
    countries1: [
        {key:"1", val:"Albania"},
        {key:"5", val:"Australia"},
        {key:"2", val:"United Arab Emerates"}
    ],
    countries2: [
        {key:"AL", val:"Albania"},
        {key:"AU", val:"Australia"}, 
        {key:"AE", val:"United Arab Emerates"}
    ]
};

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('select[data-jsdrop-data]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            listname = $this.attr("data-jsdrop-data"),
            list = lists[listname]; // don't use eval!
        for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            var item = list[i];
            $this.append($("<option>").val(item.key).text(item.value));
        }
    });
});
```

A for-loop is much faster and more intuitive than `$.each`. Don't use that when you don't know exactly what it does and when you need it.

Comment: Is there a way to get my list from a variable without eval and without having all my lists having to be tied to a common list array?

Comment: Thanks for your post by the way.  Using the array of objects keeps the options in the defined order ... which is exactly what I was after.

Comment: @RHarris: Not really, though you could just put variables into the list array instead of the literals. But why would you want the lists in different variables?

Comment: The function that builds the dropdown options is part of my common library.  The common lists (country, etc) are build dynamically into a separate js file.  However, the page itself could have a dropdown that needs to access a list defined locally in the page.  I suppose I could define it in the page by using $.extend(list,{})

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what to do when you need to populate the `lists` object from several scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have a numerical property on an object, that `jQuery.each()` will need to use array-type access to the property (i.e. `countries[1]`, `countries[2]`, `countries[5]`).  Because of this it will iterate through in numerical index order.

Comment: No. [`jQuery.each`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L584) checks for a `length` propery (not on function objects) and iterates the object array-like if it is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `$.each` defaults to `for( a in b )` which *does not guarantee order*. This is why you are seeing the order seem non-sequential or unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the options much more efficiently using:

```
$('select[data-jsdrop-data]').each(function() {
    var list = window[this.getAttribute('data-jsdrop-data')];
    var i = 0;
    for (var p in list) {
        this.options[i++] = new Option(p, list[p]);
    }
});
```